# How to ask a question about the first seal in Revelation 6?

Tags: discussion

I want to know if this is appropriate for this site. The guidelines for this site specifically allow asking and answering your own questions. I want to ask "Where can the criteria for the first seal in Revelation 6 be found in the rest of the Bible?" That is, in context. It is a question about the text.

YLT Revelation 6:1-2

> And I saw when the Lamb opened one of the seals, and I heard one of the four living creatures saying, as it were a voice of thunder, ‘Come and behold!’
>
> and I saw, and lo, a white horse, and he who is sitting upon it having a bow, and there was given to him a crown, and he went forth overcoming, and that he may overcome.
>
> ...

In Isaiah 7, the King of Asshur is said to bring a bow and all the land will become briars and thorns. That is in the text.

Isaiah 7:17, 24:

> ...
>
> Jehovah bringeth on thee, and on thy people, And on the house of thy father, Days that have not come, Even from the day of the turning aside of Ephraim from Judah, By the king of Asshur.
>
> ...
>
> With arrows and with bow he cometh thither, because all the land is brier and thorn.
>
> ...

Isaiah 28:1-5 says the crown of Ephraim is given to a mighty one (which historically Asshur conquered Ephraim):

> Wo to the proud crown of the drunkards of Ephraim. And the fading flower of the beauty of his glory, That is on the head of the fat valley of the broken down of wine.
>
> Lo, a mighty and strong one is to the Lord, As a storm of hail - a destructive shower, As an inundation of mighty waters overflowing, He cast down to the earth with the hand.
>
> By feet trodden down is the proud crown of the drunkards of Ephraim,
>
> And the fading flower of the beauty of his glory That is on the head of the fat valley, Hath been as its first-fruit before summer, That its beholder seeth, While it is yet in his hand he swalloweth it.
>
> In that day is Jehovah of Hosts For a crown of beauty, and for a diadem of glory, To the remnant of His people.
>
> ...

It is in the text.

Isaiah 10 talks about the king of Asshur conquering. It is in the text.

This is all about the **text**. The fact the rider has a bow is part of the text and I am attempting to **put it in context**. The type of crown mentioned depends on the **text** and I am attempting to **put it in context**. The quotes are part of the **text of the Old Testament** and you have to look back there to **put it in context**.

I am not interested in pushing a doctrinal view, I just want to show that we can find these items in these places. The **translated text** in Revelation 6:1-2 matches these places.

I asked a similar question about the sealed scroll in Revelation 5 and I was told it was a topic question, not a question about the text, and therefore it was not appropriate for this site. I deleted that one even though it was a question about the text.

Is it appropriate to post this question here? The first line of the tour for this site says, "Biblical Hermeneutics is a question and answer site for anyone who wants to know what a Biblical text means (exegesis) using the techniques or rules of interpretation (hermeneutics)," and I think I am staying true to that (correct me if I am missing something). If this question is not appropriate, is it possible to reframe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question should be reworded to be more acceptable. You state:

> "Where can the criteria for the first seal in Revelation 6 be found in the rest of the Bible?"

This phrasing *assumes* too much (that such criteria is to be found) and also asks a "where in the Bible ..." type question, which is "searching for a text," and that type of question is not allowed.

Instead, stick to the basics of what you are seeking to have interpreted:

> What does the rider on the white horse refer to?

Then you can provide as your "answer" the passages you think are relevant and why. But before you ask a question like that, be sure some of the other questions on the site do not already fit that mold (and yours then closed as a duplicate). A few that might be (and so maybe your answer ought to be posted on one of these):

1. [If one rider on the white horse represent's "Christ," does the other rider on the white horse represent the "Anti-Christ"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/11588/2070)
2. [The Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/7752/2070)

In short, do a thorough search of the site to be sure a question like what you are wanting to ask has not already been, and if yours is distinct enough, ask it.